# using ffmpeg to automate splitting video into quarters and stacking

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to create a quick FFMPEG batch file that takes a very wide video file and splits it into quarters (dimension wise not time wise), then outputting a file where each quarter is under the previous.

E.g.

A  B  C  D

Would become:

A
B
C
D

I know this should be possible with crop and pad commands, and through research I've found that someone divided into quarters and put the top left and bottom right next to each other horizontally using:

```
"%~dp0\ffmpeg.exe" -i %1 -filter_complex "[0:0]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:0,pad=iw*2:ih:0:0[tl];[0:0]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:ih/2[br];[tl][br]overlay=W/2" -b:v 32000k -b:a 128k %1_2.avi
```

Can anyone help as the command line is beyond me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: original]
[image: filtered version]

<sub>Original and "quartered & stacked" versions.</sub>

Using the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) and [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) video filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=iw/4:ih:0:0[c1]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/4:ih:ow:0[c2]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/4:ih:ow*2:0[c3]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/4:ih:ow*3:0[c4]; \
 [c1][c2][c3][c4]vstack=inputs=4[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - what is your input file called in the example above? Is it "input"? I am very new at doing complex ffmpeg commands.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking at the documentation and wrote down that I thought vstack and maybe split and pad might be needed to do this but I have never done anything like this before so it is out of my expertise.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - perfect it worked I took a 2000 wide pixel AVI and stacked it per above. I think my new output AVI maybe is not quite as good as quality as the original can you point me to how I might better the quality of the output?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - Maybe not a quality issue? I think it scaled the height of the frames way up from original? See this link for console output and original video AVI file.  [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhCFMAvOnlqvgfJ1YDlIQbXsSTC-NA)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - actually I think it scaled both height and width by probably 4 times?

Comment: @NealDavis Add `-q:v 2` output option to make less crappy output when using encoder `mpeg4`. Input quality wasn't good to begin with and output from lossy encoders will never technically equal the input quality. It should perform no scaling. 2000x48 quartered and vertically stacked results in 500x192.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - yes I just realized what happened I was playing it with MS Movies and TV  and it was scaling it up (I think because I have a HD monitor laptop). When I play it with windows media player it is correct and looks as good as can be given original quality. Thanks so much!